# Screencapture a window on MacOSX with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics, screen-capture

How would one screencapture a window that is minimized, hidden or otherwise not in focus? I believe this might be possible with Quartz...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for minimized windows, but other windows can be captured with `xwd`. You could use that or check its source how it's done. There are other options with UIKit, enter `screen capture` in Xcode Help.